# Open WPF Popup Control without focus

Tags: wpf, popup

I want to know if there is a way to open a WPF Popup without move focus to it.

When I set the property IsOpen = true of the Pupup the Applciation window lost focus (the Deactivated event is fired) and the focis is moved to  the Popup and I want to maintain the window with the focus.

I already tried the method `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement` to get the previous element with focus and then set the focus to it again but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course popup will acquire focus just to make sure that it will receive input from mouse & keyboard. what are you trying to achive? Do you want your main winow to retain focus?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Focusable` property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one thing...

1. Make your Window handle Keyboard.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus.

   ```
   <Window Keyboard.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler" ... />
   ```
2. In your handler handle the event for when popup is open.

   ```
   private void KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   {
          e.Handled = this.popup.IsOpen;
   }
   ```

Let me know if this works....